# Caching results of a Django function call with cache.get_or_set()

Tags: django, caching

This clause works fine:

```
if cache.get(cache_name):
    events = cache.get(cache_name)
else:
    events = self.get_google_events()
    cache.set(cache_name, events, 60 * 10)
```

If I put a print statement in `get_google_events()`, it's only printed if the cache is expired, as expected. But if I try to shorten the above to this:

```
events = cache.get_or_set(cache_name, self.get_google_events(), 60 * 10)
```

The print statement is fired every time (i.e. caching is silently broken). Isn't the second form equivalent to the first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not at all. Python must evaluate expressions that form part of the arguments to a function fully before calling the function itself. In your second case this means that `self.get_google_events()` will *always* be called, before `get_or_set` can determine whether or not not retrieve the value from the cache.

Note also that your first case can be made slightly more efficient: the way you have it now, you're making two calls to `get` unnecessarily. Instead, just make one:

```
events = cache.get(cache_name)
if not events:
    events = self.get_google_events()
    cache.set(cache_name, events, 60 * 10)
```

Comment: I see - I had mistakenly thought that if cache_name existed, it would do nothing else. But yes, this is just how python works. Thanks for the clear explanation (and for the shortened version).

Comment: I came here wondering a similar thing to this question. If we can't help but call the callable whenever we run `get_or_set`, what's the expected way to use the `get_or_set` API so that it actually does caching?

Comment: @mlissner Late to the party, but the issue isn't that the callable is always called by `get_or_set` – it's that in the OP's second example **they** are calling the callable at the same time as they pass it as an argument (by including the `()` brackets), so in this specific example it **is** always called. The solution is to remove the brackets (thus only passing the callable and not its result). For more complex cases where you need to pass arguments to the callable, you can wrap it in a lambda, like this: `cache.get_or_set('some-timestamp-key', lambda: my_expensive_function(foo, bar))`

Answer (score 6):

The solution is not to call the function (without **()** ).
In your case it is:

```
events = cache.get_or_set(cache_name, self.get_google_events, 60 * 10)
```

You can test it with this example from the django documentation

```
import datetime
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.get_or_set('some-timestamp-key', datetime.datetime.now)

>> datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 11, 0, 15, 49, 457920)
```

you normally call it with **datetime.datetime.now()**

see documentation [Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/)

Comment: For anyone needing to pass a callable with arguments, you can wrap it in a lambda: `cache.get_or_set('some-timestamp-key', lambda: my_expensive_function(foo, bar))`